# Getting data from openweather API in React

Tags: reactjs, api, openweathermap

I am trying to write a program that takes names of 2 cities as an input, and then gets the temperature in the 2 cities using the openweathermap API. However, I am unable to call the API. I tried following some tutorials but it is a bit confusing. I would be glad if someone could help me with connecting to the API, and getting the temperature for the cities, and print them on screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Request from 'superagent';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {input1: '', input2: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      var city1 = this.state.input1;
      var url= 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city1}&units=metric&APPID=83c6ba4dd07d83514536821a8a51d6d5';
      Request.get(url).then((response) => {
          this.setState({
              report: response.body.Search
          });
      });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
      var temperature = _.map(this.state.report, (city) => {
          return (<p>{city.main.temp}</p>);
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </header>
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Where Should I go?</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="cityboxdiv">
                <input name="input1" type="text" id="tb1" className="citybox" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter City1" autoFocus />
                <input name="input2" type="text" id="tb2" className="citybox" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter City2"/>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-div">
                <button type="submit" className="sub-btn">Tell Me!</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Two things I would like to know are how to pass the city names into the url so that we can get the data. And once we get the data, how can I display only the temperature values of the cities.

Answer (score 0):

I see you make several mistakes.

1. Request to API and put data to state you should make inside `handleSubmit` (or better use actions).
2. In render method you should output your state data as `state.report.map(item => (<div>{city.main.temp}</div>))`
3. Generate url you can make using template string (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/template-strings-javascript)